# angularjs $q & $http about promise

Tags: angularjs, http, promise, angular-promise

About $http in the offical doc:

> The $http API is based on the deferred/promise APIs exposed by the $q
>   service.
>
> The $http service is a function which takes a single argument — a
>   configuration object — that is used to generate an HTTP request and
>   returns a promise

So what's the meaning of the code below :

```
var deferred = $q.defer();
var promise = deferred.promise;
var progress;
$http.get("https://api.github.com/repos/angular/angular.js/pulls")
.success(function(data){
    var result = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        result.push(data[i].user);
        progress = (i+1)/data.length * 100;
        deferred.notify(progress);
    }
    deferred.resolve(result);
    })
.error(function(error){
    deferred.reject(error);
});
return promise;
```

If $http return a promise, why should i use $q to return a promise?

Comment: Hmmmm. That's weird. Normally you would just do something like `.success().then()`. I wonder if their docs are incredibly out of date or for some reason angular doesn't support promise chaining.

Comment: @AR7, Angular does support promise chaining, just not with the `success()` method, which is deprecated by now. For details, see my answer below. With `$http.get().then()` everything works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended way to use the `$http` service is like this:

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/someUrl'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // success code here
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    // error handling code here
  });
```

In this case you don't have to return a new promise but can just return the result of the call to `then()` as you would expect.

However, the `success()` method is a convenience method that is passed the fields of the response object as separate parameters already:

```
.then(function(response) {
  // do something with response.data, response.status, etc.
})
```

vs.

```
.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
  // do something with data, status, etc.
})
```

However, in contrast to `then()`, `success()` does not return a promise. I would not recommend to use it and I just saw in [the docs](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/docs/api/ng/service/$http), that it has been deprecated by now.

**Update:** I think the reason another promise is constructed in the example you provided is not that `success()` can be used but that the call to `deferred.notify(progress)` is possible. Without creating another promise explicitly, you wouldn't have access to the `deferred` object.

Comment: what return a promise is $http(), not success()

Comment: What do you mean? `$http.get()` returns a promise. If you call `.then()` on this promise you obtain another promise (that you can for instance return from your function). However, `success()` does not return a promise. So if you want to use `success()` you have to create another promise with `$q.defer()` and wire them together manually.

Comment: @kuma,I updated my answer. Is it clear how your code would have to be changed to avoid explicit creation of another promise? If not, I'd add it to my answer.

Comment: 3q! Got what you mean. According to what you give, I take a look at offical doc, find words below:
This method-then returns a new promise which is resolved or rejected via the return value of the successCallback, errorCallback (unless that value is a promise, in which case it is resolved with the value which is resolved in that promise using promise chaining).
I do need hands-on practice for deep understanding.

Comment: I always get a promise if I use 'then' method on a promise

Comment: That is the correct behaviour. You get a new promise that is resolved with the value you return in the success callback passed to `then`. You can for instance transform the retrieved data in the success callback (you should in case of `$http.get`).

Comment: This article helped me a lot to understand promises: https://blog.domenic.me/youre-missing-the-point-of-promises/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101086/discussion-between-lex82-and-kuma).

Answer (score 0):

$http is returning a promise, which we use and thus have the 'success' (can also use 'then'). If you use this $http call in a service and call this service method from your controller then you will want to return a promise from that method, so you can use .then and .catch etc

Answer (score 0):

A **new instance** of deferred is constructed by calling $q.defer().
The purpose of the deferred object is to expose the associated Promise instance as well as APIs

that can be used for signaling the **successful** or **unsuccessful** completion, as well as the status of the
task.

$q is integrated with the $rootScope.Scope Scope model observation mechanism in angular, which means faster propagation of resolution or rejection into your models and avoiding unnecessary browser repaints, which would result in flickering UI.

refernce: Official Doc